# Как сохранить сгенерированный с помощью tcpdf pdf файл на сервере?

Tags: pdf, tcpdf, php

Как сохранить сгенерированный с помощью tcpdf pdf файл на сервере?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого у библиотеки TCPDF есть метод `Output`.

> CPDF::Output($name = 'doc.pdf', $dest = 'I')
>
> Send the document to a given destination: string, local file or browser. In the last case, the plug-in may be used (if present) or a download ("Save as" dialog box) may be forced. The method first calls Close() if necessary to terminate the document.

http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a3d6dcb62298ec9d42e9125ee2f5b23a1